# Add action to custom Function

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, actions

I am trying to use plugin action in my custom function. Plugin is adding an action to wordpress registration form

```
add_action( 'bp_before_account_details_fields', 'tv_bp_avatar_upload_form' );
```

But i want to use this in my custom registration form **( inside custom_registration() )** please suggest me how to add this action to my function.

Thanks

Comment: Tell us more bout  inside custom_registration(), is it a function in a plugin you are writing? Or is it in a template?

Comment: it is in a template

Answer (score 1):

You can simpy call the action yourself:

```
do_action( 'bp_before_account_details_fields' );
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action